# MATLAB: Conditionally define get/set class methods

Tags: matlab, oop

I have created some MATLAB classes to do some error-checking when I use certain types of structures. This improve development time by preventing errors in the code, but significantly slow down execution time.

One way to get around this is to comment out the set methods inside the class. Is it possible to do this programmatically? For example, only define these methods if a parameter in the constructor is true.

```
classdef MWE
    %MWE     Minimum working example

    properties
        A
        B
        C
    end

    methods
        function obj = MWE(A, B, C)
            if nargin ~= 3
                error('A, B and C must all be provided.');
            end

            obj.A = A;
            obj.B = B;
            obj.C = C;
        end

%         function obj = set.A(obj, value)
%             validate(obj, value, 'A');
%             obj.A = value;
%         end
%                 
%         function obj = set.B(obj, value)
%             validate(obj, value, 'B');
%             obj.B = value;
%         end
%         
%         function obj = set.C(obj, value)
%             validate(obj, value, 'C');
%             obj.C = value;
%         end

    end

    methods (Access = private)
        function validate(obj, value, name)
            % Code here
        end 
    end
end
```

Comment: Not very familiar with classes in MATLAB, but with functions I often put in an error checking logical variable. `if debug; do debug stuff; end`. `Do rest of code`

Comment: A simple, concrete implementation of your code would help others see your problem more clearly.

Comment: How are you hoping that removing the set methods of the class will speed things up? Why do you need to have set methods in the first place - are you just doing error-checking there? Could you add some example code?

Comment: "Using a set or get function will turn off most optimizations and also introduce the extra time to call the set or get function which is generally much greater than the time to just access the property." https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/03/26/considering-performance-in-object-oriented-matlab-code/#3

This is consistent with my experience - commenting out the setter methods significantly improves performance. I know in some languages (eg. Python?) objects can have methods added in a manner similar to property assignment, and I was wondering if there is anything similar in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do this programmatically? For example, only define these methods if a parameter in the constructor is true.

After some discussion, I see there are different ways of looking at your question.  And, indeed, it may be that you cannot do what you are asking as interpreted by some.  Here are two cases, however, that may suffice.

- ## Case 1

  You have computationally intensive or otherwise time consuming methods, that you use to "do some error-checking", in a development setting, but want to turn off in a production environment.  And, these checks occur when the class is instantiated.

Place these methods in a wrapper function that is called from the constructor.

Here's an example

```
classdef classFoo
   properties(Access=private)
       fbar;
   end
   methods
       function this = classFoo(arg1, argN, debugMode)  
           if(nargin>2 && debugMode)
               if(~this.verifyStuff(arg1, argN))
                   throw(MException('classFoo:ConstructFailure','Could not verify'));
               else
                    this.fbar = timeConsumingFunction();
               end
           else
               this.fbar = 42; % defaultValue;
           end           
           % continue construction

       end
       function didVerify = verifyStuff(this, varargin)
           % complex code
           didVerify = randi(2)-1;  % 50/50
       end
   end
end
```

Then when creating objects you can choose to pass the debug mode flag as true like this:

```
a=classFoo(1,2,true)
```

or as false, like this:

```
a=classFoo(1,2,false)
```

or not at all, which is the same as the false case, like this:

```
a=classFoo(1,2)
```

- ### Case 2

  You have two different versions of a get/set method that you are commenting out depending on your development environment.

Add a private member parameter (e.g. `isDebugging`) and set it at time of construction.  Now, instead of commenting out code in your get and set methods, you can handle the different cases with a simple if/else, predicated on your debug state like this:

```
classdef classFoo
   properties(Access=private)
       fbar;
       isDebugging;
   end
   methods
       function this = classFoo(debugMode)  
           if(nargin<1 || ~islogical(debugMode))
               debugMode = false;
           end
           this.isDebugging = debugMode;
        end
        function setfbar(this, fIn)
             if(this.isDebugging)
                 this.fbar = timeConsumingFunction(fIn);
             else
               this.fbar = fIn; % defaultValue;
           end           
        end
   end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question at all. Your example class has no set methods, and the method it does have (`verifyStuff`) is defined whether or not `debugMode` is true.

Comment: @SamRoberts Actually, I think this answers the question quite well as I understood it.  I understood the question as, "Is it  possible to have a constructor only perform some _error checking_ that _significantly slows down execution time_ when _a parameter in the constructor is true_".  Of course, looking at your comments above, it seems you are interpreting the question differently, in a way that makes little sense to me.  I'll leave it to the OP to respond with clarification if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: To explain my point: `verifyStuff` in your class is not a set method. If your class has a property `foo`, a _set method_ for `foo` is a special method named `set.foo` that is responsible for setting the property, and possibly, as the questioner discussed, other things such as error-checking the value to which the property is being set. The OP is asking whether it's possible to cause the constructor to "programmatically comment out" these set methods. It isn't possible, but I've asked for further information as it might be possible to do something similar.

Comment: I understand your point and what is generally understood as a _set method_.  However, I don't think that is what the OP meant given their emphasis on error checking and execution time in the question.  This is what I gravitated toward in my response.  Perhaps a highly computational method is evaluated to determine the a variable under development conditions, while a cached result is used to initialize or set the variable otherwise.  I hope it is clear that they will put the computationally intensive stuff inside the `verifyStuff` method.